# Any way to speed up this UPDATE?

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, winforms

SQL:

```sql
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.fnRandomForeNames ()
RETURNS VARCHAR(50) 
AS
BEGIN
RETURN  (
            SELECT TOP 1 [FirstName]
            FROM [tmp_ForeNames] 
            ORDER BY (SELECT new_id from GetNewID)
        )
END
GO
```

Similar functions for dbo.fnRandomSurNames() etc.

```sql
UPDATE Table1
SET firstname = dbo.fnRandomForeNames(),
    lastname = dbo.fnRandomSurNames(),
    address1 = dbo.fnRandomAddress1(),
    address2 = dbo.fnRandomAddress2(),
    address3 = dbo.fnRandomAddress3(),
    birthdate = DATEADD(DAY, ABS(CHECKSUM(NEWID()) % 3650), '1990-01-01')
```

My C# Code:

```
    private void RunThis(string connString, StreamReader sr)
    {
        sr.BaseStream.Position = 0;
        string sqlQuery = sr.ReadToEnd();
        using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connString))
        {
            Server server = new Server(new ServerConnection(connection));
            server.ConnectionContext.StatementTimeout = 4200;
            server.ConnectionContext.ExecuteNonQuery(sqlQuery);
        }
        sr.Close();
    }
```

........

```
 RunThis(e.Argument.ToString(), _updateClaim);
```

Where `e.Argument.ToString()` is the connection string.

The `CREATE FUNCTION` scripts are run earlier, take very little time to run.
Also, names are stored in tmp databases, these are entered in C# via arrays.
These also take very little time to run.

Table1 contains approx 140,000 rows and takes approx. 14 mins to complete.

I have also tried using parameterised SQL queries, skipping the tmp tables and SQL functions and instead creating the SQL query and executing it from the code, such as the following:

```sql
UPDATE Table1
SET lastname = '{0}',
    firstname = '{1}',
    birthdate = DATEADD(DAY, ABS(CHECKSUM(NEWID()) % 3650), '1990-01-01'),
    address1 = '{2}',
    address2 = '{3}',
    address3 = '{4}'
    WHERE u_id = '{6}'
```

And some C#:

```
 using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connString))
        {
            connection.Open();
            for (int i = 0; i < arraySize; ++i)
            {
                string updateString = string.Format(updateString2, GetRandomSurname(), GetRandomForeName(), GetRandomAddress1(), GetRandomAddress2(), GetRandomAddress3(), "", ids[i]);
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(updateString, connection);
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
        }
```

The latter method also taking upwards of 14 minutes.

Any ideas on how to cut down the time it takes to update the table?

Comment: Just a note:
what you call a "parametrised query" is not actually it. In parametrised query you refer to parameters like @id, and add SqlParameter objects when running, not use string.Format.

Comment: To add to @ElDog's comment, using actual parametrized queries is a good idea, using `string.Format()` this way is not.

Comment: Additionally, using a real parameterized query is likely to cause a significant speed-up, because SQL will only have to calculate the execution plan the first time it is run.  With string.Format building, it has to re-calculate every time the values change.  Parsing the query in this case is likely to be the most expensive step of executing the query.

Comment: Just as an update to this, I have tried using parameterised queries(correctly) but have come into the issue of only being allowed a max of 2100 queries per execution, I have tried to get around this by breaking it up into seperate queries but I couldn't get it to work. Will post code later. Thanks for replies.

Answer (score 3):

Not sure what that `ORDER BY (SELECT new_id from GetNewID)`, but comparing the following approaches, second is much faster and spends most of the time in COUNT(*), which could be pre-calculated.

```
SELECT TOP 1 name FROM master.sys.all_objects ORDER BY NEWID()

DECLARE @n int
SELECT @n = RAND() * (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM master.sys.all_objects)

SELECT name FROM (
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT 1)) as n, name
    FROM master.sys.all_objects
) AS names
WHERE n = @n
```

I guess you could make it even faster by materializing integer sequential `id` inside your names tables and making a clustered index on that.

Answer (score 2):

indexes!  Index on new_id.

You say you're using temp tables, so I assume you're populating them all at once. Do a update statistics after you fill them.

Finally, why cant you say something like this?

```
 select firstName from tmp_ForeNames where new_id = getNewId()
```

order by takes time so you should avoid it if possible.